# Experience with paid English grammar and style software for writing papers?

Tags: writing, writing-style, software

I'm looking to suggest to our institute to invest in a paid software for helping writing, along the lines of Grammarly Premium, Antidote 10 or something similar. Does anyone have any experience with any of these, in particular for writing papers in STEM? Can you comment on how valuable these are?

Comment: Check the software with this - note I have used this a long time ago and the common software failed then and tested recently it still failed so it has not progressed much : http://www.phys-astro.sonoma.edu/people/faculty/tenn/SpellingChequer.html

Comment: I'm not looking for software that magically fixes gibberish. I'm looking for software which saves time by highlighting grammar and style issues before a manuscript is passed to colleagues to proofread.